# Resizing input size on focus and blur in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, input

I'm trying to change the input size from 20 to 100 each time it ng-focus. Then, when it ng-blur, it should convert from 100 to 20. Here is my html code:

```
<div ng-controller="MenuCtrl" class="navbar-collapse collapse bs-navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-blur="{[{ change_text_width() }]}" ng-focus="{[{ change_text_width() }]}" size="{[{search_text_width}]}" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Before my angular module, I put a parent module:

```
var JobMaps = angular.module('JobMaps', ['MenuCtrl']);
```

Here is my angular code:

```
var MenuCtrl = angular.module('MenuCtrl',[]);
MenuCtrl.controller = angular.module('MenuCtrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.search_text_width = 20;
  $scope.change_text_width = function() {
    if ($scope.search_text_width==20) {
      $scope.search_text_width = 100;
      //alert($scope.search_text_width);
    } else {
      $scope.search_text_width = 20;
      //alert($scope.search_text_width);
    }
  }
});
```

**Observation:**

1. I tried to alert it, and it seems like it runs several times.
2. I think it may be converting from 20 to 100 and 100 to 20 back so fast, I could not see it... Well, it could be a possibility because of several alerts that popup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Angular world you use directives for DOM manipulation. One advantage is that you can reuse the directives without much extra code and seperate the UI stuff from the controller. I created a plunker for the resizing input: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MlXC93XXMLMkQQeDLJua?p=preview)

Comment: This is also achievable by CSS if you don't want to write a directive, but arguably not the "Angular Way"

Comment: Yes, I've tried the CSS. Somehow, I was trying to put my program in the perfect angular way. This way, it can reflect pure html.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the attribute `size` because `width` can affect the responsiveness when using Bootstrap.

```
MenuCtrl.directive('changeSize', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
      var onFocusSize = $attributes['changeSize'] || $element.attr('size');
      var onBlurSize = $element.attr('size');
      $element.focus(function() { $element.attr('size',onFocusSize); });
      $element.blur(function() { $element.attr('size',onBlurSize); });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Just added some variety. I'm still thinking how to deal with the effects or animate, though.